# Issue while executing npm commands

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

We are facing the below issue while running npm commands multiple times on a machine at the same time.

This issue occurs randomly. Couldn't find any root cause.

Details are attached to below error log

**Error log:**

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'run',
    1 verbose cli   'coverage' ]
    2 info using npm@5.3.0
    3 info using node@v6.4.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'precoverage', 'coverage', 'postcoverage' ]
    5 info lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~precoverage: gulp-karma@1.0.0
    6 info lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: gulp-karma@1.0.0
    7 verbose lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage:
    9 verbose lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: CWD: D:\workspace\TestGroup\viewer
    10 silly lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
    10 silly lifecycle   'concurrently "gulp common" "gulp feature" "gulp file" "gulp layout" "gulp widget_zero" "gulp widget_one" "gulp mobile_common" "gulp mobile_feature" "gulp mobile_file" "gulp mobile_layout" "gulp mobile_widget"' ]
    11 silly lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle gulp-karma@1.0.0~coverage: Failed to exec coverage script
    13 verbose stack Error: gulp-karma@1.0.0 coverage: `concurrently "gulp common" "gulp feature" "gulp file" "gulp layout" "gulp widget_zero" "gulp widget_one" "gulp mobile_common" "gulp mobile_feature" "gulp mobile_file" "gulp mobile_layout" "gulp mobile_widget"`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    14 verbose pkgid gulp-karma@1.0.0
    15 verbose cwd D:\workspace\TestGroup\viewer
    16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "coverage"
    18 verbose node v6.4.0
    19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error gulp-karma@1.0.0 coverage: `concurrently "gulp common" "gulp feature" "gulp file
```

It would be grateful if someone helps me to get resolve

Comment: What command are you using to get this error ?

Comment: @BozhinovskiVladimir npm run coverage

Comment: Try clearing node_modules and npm installing after that.

Comment: @BozhinovskiVladimir We are facing this issue when running npm commands multiple times from different powershell prompt (3) at the same time. So, clearing node_modules won't affect the other two process? Note: In clear, three automation are scheduled in a machine for Continuous Integration process with Jenkins.

Comment: we are using different ports to run the commands for each karma configuration. will it be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your command `concurrently` returns with an "EXIT_FAILURE" exit code, this **can** be caused by an javascript error by the inside any of your gulp tasks. Since i don't know what these tasks do i can't really help you on that. You could run each command on it's own to find the one who returns the error.